# Angular 2 Material: Apply class based on current resolution

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using Angular 4 and Angular Material for it, and I'm searching the way to apply class depending on current resolution. I'm searching for something like this (using Angular Material's breakpoints):

```
<div [ngClass]="{'no-left-margin': AngularMaterialBreakpoint}"></div>
```

Or alternatively:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'no-left-margin': window.screen.width < 1280}"></div>
```

But the first method is more preferable. I have already checked the second method and it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webstorm suggest me the solution: Angular Material has nice built-in attribute, and we can use it like this:

```
<div class.lt-lg="class-to-apply"></div>
```

And `class-to-apply` class will be applied for screen resolutions with width smaller than 1280px. But I didn't find anything in the docks about it, thanks to Webstorm's autocomplete.

Comment: you are likely picking that up from flexlayout - https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Responsive-API